# Calling Service With Pageable Parameter - Best Practice Question

Tags: java, rest, web-services, spring-boot, pagination

I have a service `MyMainService` that makes a call to another service `MySecondaryService` within the same package.  The method `getPagesOfMyObjects` being called in `MySecondaryService` returns a Page of objects of type `MyObject` and one of the method's parameters is a `Pageable` object.  `MyMainService` is, at present, not concerned with pagination.  But because I need to call the `getPagesOfMyObjects` method in `MySecondaryService` I need to provide it with a `Pageable` object that won't exclude any records that I might need.  My current solution (not very good) is to pass this as the `Pageable` parameter

```
public class MyMainServiceImpl implements MyMainService {

    @Autowired
    private MySecondaryService mySecondaryService

    public void myMethod() {
        Page<MyObject> pages = mySecondaryService.getPagesOfMyObjects(PageRequest.of(0, 10000));
        List<MyObject> myObjects = pages.getContent();
        //do stuff
    }

}
```

As you can see it has 10000 hard-coded as its size parameter.  This doesn't feel like good practice to me.  Is there a better way to call this service?  I don't have the option of re-writing the existing `getPagesOfMyObjects` method.

Answer (score 0):

In the end I used `Pageable.unpaged()` as a parameter in place of `PageRequest.of(0, 10000)`, which seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

Why would you pass pageable and unwrap the content if you don't need pagination in the first place?
Assuming `mySecondaryService` is yours, you can add an unpaged `findAll` method to it and use that one.

```
List<MyObject> myObjects = mySecondaryService.getAllMyObjects();
```

(Btw, `Pageable.unpaged()` does the same under the hood)